# свой тип в F# ограничивающий диапазон базового числового типа

Tags: f#

Есть ли возможность в F# создать свой тип, который ограничивал бы базовый тип некоторым диапазоном? Что-то, что условно могло бы выглядеть вот так

```
type myInt = Value of int when Value > 1000 & Value < 1000;
```

и запрещало бы на этапе компиляции присваивать невалидные значения

```
let a : myInt = 1000; //ошибка, не компилируется
```

Comment: [How to define IntsWithoutZero type in f#](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/285777)

Comment: это не совсем то, просто тип, который заменяет 0 другим значением (вернее это только полдела) я и без него мог бы написать:

Comment: Нет, там пример проверки в конструкторе, в которой ты можешь проверить свой интервал

Comment: Я понимаю про проверку, но такой род проверки происходит в рантайме жеш. Мне знакомый рассказывал, что в Хаскеле ест возможность написать тип, которому ты просто не сможешь присвоить 0, тебе компилятор не даст. А тут ты можешь присвоить 0, просто получишь None, но я не вижу разницы потом в сопоставлениях проверять на 0 или на None, профит как раз в том, чтобы получить тип, которому принципиально проверки не нужны

Comment: _А тут ты можешь присвоить 0, просто получишь None_ - там можно исключение кидать вместо возврата

Comment: которое надо будет потом перехватывать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такой возможности в F# пока нет.

Подобные предложения время от время появляются, можете почитать обсуждение, например, в следующем ишшуе:

[New type: constrained type #553](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/553)

То, что вы описываете называется [зависимым типом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF) (dependent type). Для F# есть библиотеки, например:

[DependentTypes](https://github.com/jackfoxy/DependentTypes)

Ошибку во время компиляции не даст, но спасет от многократного написания подобного кода:

```
module String100 = 
    type T = String100 of string
    let create (s:string) = 
        if s <> null && s.Length <= 100 
        then Some (String100 s) 
        else None
    let apply f (String100 s) = f s
    let value s = apply id s
```

пример взят из [Designing with types: Constrained strings](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-more-semantic-types/)

Также можно написать свой type provider взяв за основу [ConstraintTP](https://github.com/Lleutch/ConstraintTP), но аналога [liquidhaskell](https://ruhaskell.org/posts/utils/2016/12/16/liquidhaskell-hello.html) вы тем самым тоже не добъетесь.

Можно подумать над написанием собственного анализатора, но, на мой взгляд, эта затея не стоит свеч, так как все равно придется обрабатывать преобразование к вашему типу через Option, Result или выбрасывая исключения при получении данных извне.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения! Про liquidhaskell почитал, да, это как раз то, чего хотелось бы. А вообще я начинаю понимаю, что метапрограммирование на .Net это скорее Reflection